# create sites internally hosted

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, website

At my work we are using sharepoint for an intranet (acessed internally)

so if you go to http://intranet you will be redirected to the intranet site.

I want to create other sites that make use active directory but can only be accessed internaly.

i.e. if I create a site, how can i set it up such that if anyone internally types 
http://myinternalsite then they can view a site that can only be accessed by employees internally?

or is there a better way of doing this?

the idea being i can create numerous in house tools (in the form of websites) and i can choose to name it whatever i want, which can then be accessed internally by staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with Active Directory, but with DNS. When you create each site you'll create a DNS A record on the internal DNS server that corresponds to the host portion of the URL that you want the site to be accessible at, such as myinternalsite. Then in the web site you'll create host headers that correspond to the DNS A record.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a site is accessible internally only is decided by a number of factors:

1. Is the server hosting the site accessible from the outside?
2. Do the sitenames get resolved in public DNS and does the IP address then point to that server?
3. Is there a firewall?

Under normal circumstances you can simply create additional sites in Sharepoint, add the desired names to the host headers and make sure that your intyernal DNS resolves these names to the (internal) IP address of the server. As long as this server is not accessible from the Internet, you are fine.